# PHP, sql Dynamic query with possible LIKE and OR and AND all together not working the right way

Tags: php, mysql, search, operators, combinations

I have a search form (searching for properties,real estate):

**The HTML :**  *labels ommited*

```
 <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="keywords"/>

<select name="status" id="select-property-status" class="search-select">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Tous</option>
    <option value="1">Sale</option>
    <option value="0">Rent</option>
</select>

<select name="type" id="select-property-type" class="search-select">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Tous</option>
    <option value="appartement">Appartement</option>
    <option value="duplex">Duplex</option>
    <option value="studio">Studio</option>
    <option value="villa">Villa</option>
</select>

<select name="emplacement" id="select-property-emplacement" class="search-select">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Tous</option>
    <option value="La Goulette">La Goulette</option>
    <option value="Gammarth">Gammarth</option>
    <option value="La Marsa">La Marsa</option>
    <option value="El Mourouj">El Mourouj</option>
</select>

  <input name="surface_min" type="text" placeholder="min" value=""  />
  <input name="surface_max" type="text" placeholder="max" value=""  />

  <input name="rooms_min" type="text" placeholder="min" value=""  />
  <input name="rooms_max" type="text" placeholder="max" value=""  />

  <input name="price_min" type="text" placeholder="Prix min" value=""  />
  <input name="price_max" type="text" placeholder="Prix max" value=""  />

  <input type="hidden" name="search_form" value="True" required="required"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"  class="search-button" />
```

Now **search-results.php :**

```
    // Saving search terms in variables 
    $keyword = strtolower(htmlspecialchars($_POST['keywords'])); // string from text field
    $status = htmlspecialchars($_POST['status']); // 0 or 1
    $type = htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']); // string value from option
    $emplacement = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emplacement']); // string value from option
    $surface_min = htmlspecialchars($_POST['surface_min']); // integer from text field
    $surface_max = htmlspecialchars($_POST['surface_max']);// integer from text field
    $chambres_min = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rooms_min']);// integer from text field
    $chambres_max = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rooms_max']);// integer from text field
    $prix_min = htmlspecialchars($_POST['price_min']);// integer from text field
    $prix_max = htmlspecialchars($_POST['price_max']);// integer from text field

    // create an empty array
    $where_array = array();

    // if user type in or choose an option in the search form 
    // > create a string with its value and put it in $where_array
    if($keyword != '') $where_array[] = ' LOWER(prop_title) LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%" OR LOWER(prop_desc) LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"';
    if($status != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_status = '.$status.'';
    if($type != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_type = "'.$type.'"';
    if($emplacement != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_place = "'.$emplacement.'"';
    if($surface_min != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_surface >= '.$surface_min.'';
    if($surface_max != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_surface <= '.$surface_max.'';
    if($rooms_min != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_rooms >= '.$rooms_min.'';
    if($rooms_max != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_rooms <= '.$rooms_max.'';
    if($price_min != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_price >= '.$price_min.'';
    if($price_max != '') $where_array[] = 'prop_price <= '.$price_max.'';

    // join all the array elements (the strings) saved in $where_array by the string : AND 
    $where_string = implode(" AND ", $where_array);

   // the sql query        
    $search = "SELECT * FROM proprietes WHERE $where_string";
    $search = $db->query($search);

    // if the query exists 
    if($search)
    {
        // loop through all the properies that matches the WHERE conditions
        foreach($search as $search_result)
        {
            // echo the title of the property
            echo htmlspecialchars($search_result['prop_title']);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // which one is right ?
        echo 'Error occured !';
        echo 'No property found !';
    }
```

**The problem**

All search fields works fine when selected seperately, all combinations works fine except for :
the keyword AND status fields, returned data from proprietes table where it shouldn't : i put the word " villa " in text field then chose only " For Sale " in select box (sale = 1, rent = 0) but the result gave me all villas for sale and rent !  I used `$search->debugDumpParams();` to echo this :

`SELECT * FROM proprietes WHERE LOWER(prop_title) LIKE "%villa%" OR LOWER(prop_desc) LIKE "%villa%" AND prop_status = 1`

I am thinking it's both my logic and the syntax that are wrong ! Any help please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try putting keyword search between brackets like `( LOWER(prop_title) LIKE "%villa%" OR LOWER(prop_desc) LIKE "%villa%" ) AND prop_status = 1`

Comment: Put the echo'd query into phpmyadmin ( or whatever you use) and run the query, debug it there and then refactor the query and then the code accordingly

Comment: Why not just make a `String` instead of having a `$where_array` that you later implode? Just saying. `AND` takes precedence over `OR`. Use parentheses to overcome the problem.

Comment: @mim Thanks , that was it !

Comment: @RiggsFolly am sooo new to this that your comment sounded like chinese, lol, am using phpmyadmin in wamp, guess i'll google for a " debug sql query with phpmyadmin " next time ^^

Comment: @PHPglue Thank you, parentheses did the trick, and i will remember the logic of AND over the OR.
As for imploding string elements, am using user inputs from multiples fields so i can't know which field or which field combination will be used !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change this line of code to

```
if($keyword != '') 
   $where_array[] = ' (LOWER(prop_title) LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%" OR LOWER(prop_desc) LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%")';
```

it will correct your query.

It may also be more readable if you use double quotes then you dont need all the `.` concatenation and the code becomes a little easier to read.

```
if($keyword != '') 
    $where_array[] = " (LOWER(prop_title) LIKE '%$keyword%' OR LOWER(prop_desc) LIKE '%$keyword%')";
```

Comment: That's it, it worked !  I should have remembered my maths ;)  
As for LOWER, am still working local using wamp and i do need it, i tested it without first and found out that LIKE is case sensitive ! That's why.
But i am not really sure since am sooo new to this ! THANK YOU ^^

Comment: AS for LOWER it may well be dependant on collation so I would leave it as it is for now

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot here, but your output query shows the problem.

The non-specified boolean criteria (the `AND` and `OR`) are being used incorrectly.   It should be more like this

```
SELECT * FROM proprietes 
WHERE prop_status = 1
AND (LOWER(prop_title) LIKE "%villa%" OR LOWER(prop_desc) LIKE "%villa%")
```

You will need to change your logic in your arrays to behave more like this.  In other words, anywhere you have an `OR` in your query, it should be enclosed within parentheses